# Why is Grunt installing so many folders in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, frontend, package-managers

I'm using grunt for the first time in a long while, and my hunch is I'm using it wrong. When I run `npm install grunt --save-dev`, my npm_modules folder is getting loaded with dozens of folders (87, to be exact). My expectation, and what I see when I watch tutorials, is that a single folder called grunt should be added. Similarly when I try to add the uglify plugin (`npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev`), I get an extra 31 folders added to node_modules. I remember just getting a single folder with the plugin name. I'm using:

npm version 3.9.3
grunt version 1.0.1
OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "the description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can u tell what are the folders added other than grunt and grunt-contrib-uglify

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using NPM version 3 which [flattens the dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3). Dependencies of the modules you have installed, can be installed under your node_modules folder as well. You can compare this to how Bower handles transient dependencies.

From the docs:

> While npm2 installs all dependencies in a nested way, npm3 tries to mitigate the deep trees and redundancy that such nesting causes. npm3 attempts this by installing some secondary dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) in a flat way, in the same directory as the primary dependency that requires it.

This behaviour is thus expected, you're not doing anything wrong.

If you're still running NPM version 2, you might have noticed it shows warning messages concerning this change in dependency resolution:

> The peer dependency phantomjs-prebuilt@>=1.9 included
>   from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no longer
>   be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks so much @Anzeo. I appreciate the help. I never would have guessed that something like uglify had so many dependencies.